# WPF - ToolTip in TextBlock that use the Text Property from the TextBlock

Tags: wpf, binding, tooltip, textblock, relativesource

We have many TextBlocks in our application and many of them must have ToolTips.
Often the ToolTip should display the same as the `TextBlock.Text` property.
Also the ToolTip should not be displayed if the TextBlock.Text = `""` or `null`.

So we have this solution in many many places:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding SomeTextProperty}, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}" />
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Notice:

- I have to specify the `SomeTextProperty` three times on each TextBlock that need a TooLTip with this functionality.
  This seems very redundant!
- The `ToolTip.Content` is a TextBlock itself.
  This is because I need to have a Style on the TextBlock.
  I have omitted that style to keep this post as simple as possible.

So I have tried to invent a Style for TextBlocks that use `Bindings` with `RelativeSource` to get the `TextBlock.Text` property for the ToolTip. I came up with this solution:

#### MainWindow (Just copy-paste more or less)

```
<Window x:Class="Main.Views.ToolTips"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main.Views"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Main.Converters"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ToolTips" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockWithToolTipStyle">
            <Style.Resources>
                <converters:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StringToVisibilityConverter" />
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <ToolTip.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}}" />
                        </ToolTip.Content>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <TextBlock Text="This should display a tooltip" />
        <TextBlock Text="asdf" 
                   Background="Gray"
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockWithToolTipStyle}" />

        <Separator Height="50" Visibility="Hidden" />

        <TextBlock Text="This should not display a tooltip" />
        <TextBlock Text="" 
                   Background="LightGray"
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockWithToolTipStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

#### StringToVisibilityConverter

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = value is null ? string.Empty : value.ToString();
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This, of course, don't work!
I put a breakpoint in the StringToVisibilityConverter and that breakpoint is not hit when I hover both TextBlocks in the Window.

In VS's `XAML Binding Failures` view I see two binding errors that regards `ToolTip.Visibility` and `TextBlock.Text`:

- ToolTip.Visibility: Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock', AncestorLevel='1'
- TextBlock.Text: Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock', AncestorLevel='1'

Is this possible to solve?
If so, how?

/BR,
Steffe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ToolTip` is not part of the visual tree. That's why your `Binding.RelativeSource` does not resolve.

To reference the element that is decorated by the `ToolTip` you must reference the `ToolTip.PlacementTarget` property:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}, Path=PlacementTarget.Text}" />
```

Furthermore, you should not try to toggle the `ToolTip.Visibility`. It won't work.
Instead use a `Trigger` to set the `ToolTip`.

The correct solution would be as followed:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBlock"
       x:Key="TextBlockWithToolTipStyle">
  <Style.Resources>
    <ToolTip x:Key="ToolTip">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}, Path=PlacementTarget.Text}" />
    </ToolTip>
  </Style.Resources>

  <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{StaticResource ToolTip}" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you @BionicCode for the solution and explanation :)

Comment: Thanks for the insights, especially the use if the multi datatrigger is inspiring.  I figure I still lack a deeper understanding of the fine nuances of when to use binding / templatebinding and trigger / datatrigger.

Comment: @Dom `{TemplateBinding PropertyPath}` and `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PropertyPath}` are used when inside a `ControlTemplate` (e.g. of a `Button`) and you want to bind internals of this template to the properties of the templated parent (e.g. the templated `Button`). In all other cases you use `Binding`. [TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#remarks).

Comment: @Dom You use `Trigger` (or `MultiTrigger`) when the triggers are used inside a `Style` or `ControlTemplate` and target the templated or styled control directly. In this case there is no binding necessary. If you need binding because the triggering properties of the trigger are outside the template or the target object of the current `Style` you use `DataTrigger` (or `MultiDataTrigger`), because `DataTrigger` supports data binding to define the trigger source explicitly.